# Kafka Synchronous Communication/Two way communication using ReplyingKafkaTemplate causing Lags in Response / Reply Topic

Tags: spring-kafka

We are having several microservices in our product, there are some business use cases where one microservice (TryServiceOne) have to delegate request to another microservice (TryServiceThree). For this end user is waiting for response from API. So we used ReplyingKafkaTemplate So that we can instantly respond back to Caller. Everything seems to be working, but we are seeing LAGs in REPLY Topic which is causing our Alert system to bombard with alerts. But behind the scenes messages are getting read by RequestReplyFuture and processed successfully lag is keep increasing from Kafka broker. Please suggest how to avoid LAGs.

**IMPORTANT**
We are using cluster deployment of microservices with more than one node. Hence we are using Custom Partitioning to assign response/ reply topic to one partition all the time.

**TryServiceOne**
KafkaConfiguration.class

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

@Bean
    public Map<String,Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        return props;
    }

  @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, RequestModel> requestProducerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

  @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, RequestModel> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(requestProducerFactory());
    }
@Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, RequestModel, ResponseModel> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, RequestModel> pf,
                                                                                                        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, ResponseModel> container){
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);

    }

@Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, ResponseModel> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, ResponseModel> cf) {
        TopicPartitionOffset topicPartitionOffset = new TopicPartitionOffset("RESPONSE_TOPIC",0);

        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topicPartitionOffset);
       
       containerProperties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
         return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
    }
```

My SendAndReceive Service Component looks like below

```
RequestModel requestModel= new RequestModel();
        distributorRequestEvent.setDistributorModel(producerRecord);
        // create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, RequestModel> record = new ProducerRecord<String, RequestModel>("REQUEST_TOPIC", requestModel);
        // set reply topic in header
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, "RESPONSE_TOPIC".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

       
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

        LOGGER.info("Sending message ... {}",producerRecord);

        RequestReplyFuture<String, RequestModel, ResponseModel> sendAndReceive = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
        // confirm if producer produced successfully
        SendResult<String, RequestModel> sendResult = sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();

 
        // get consumer record
        ConsumerRecord<String, ResponseModel> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();


        return consumerRecord.value();
```

**TryServiceThree Microservice**
*Kafka Configuration*

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupId);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,RequestModel.class);
        return props;
    }

@Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG,CustomPartitioner.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        return props;
    }

 @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, RequestModel> requestConsumerFactory() {
        JsonDeserializer<RequestModel> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(RequestModel.class);
        deserializer.setRemoveTypeHeaders(false);
        deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
        deserializer.setUseTypeMapperForKey(true);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                deserializer);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, RequestModel>> requestListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, RequestModel> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(requestConsumerFactory());
     //   factory.setMessageConverter(new JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(replyTemplate());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, ResponseModel> replyProducerFactory() {
        ProducerFactory<String, ResponseModel> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        return producerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, ResponseModel> replyTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(replyProducerFactory());
    }
```

CustomPartitioning on TryServiceThree

```
public class CustomPartitioner implements Partitioner {
    @Override
    public int partition(String s, Object o, byte[] bytes, Object o1, byte[] bytes1, Cluster cluster) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
containerProperties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
```

in the reply container.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Russel, I made above property in reply listener container, it thrown following error  org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'replyContainer'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use AckMode.RECORD with a batch listener
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
 at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:170)

Comment: Sorry; use `AckMode.BATCH`.

Comment: It solved by keeping AckMode.BATCH in local environment (where single instance of service and single Broker in local), thank you @GaryRussel for helping out. Whereas It's not resolved in Higher environment where we have two containers for each microservice and with Three Brokers setup. I can see LAGs increasing and keep bombard with following exception Consumer exception KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is o.a.k.c.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member

Comment: KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records

Comment: I see you are new here; don't put stuff like that in comments; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so. What you are seeing makes no sense to me; it implies that the reply container is taking too long (more than 5 minutes by default) to handle the replies. As you can see, the template's `onMessage()` method is very lightweight; so there is something strange going on. DEBUG logging might help you figure it out.